# How to define classification formats for each theme

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsx

In my editor extension I use custom classification formats for keywords, identifiers and so on. Of course, there are default formats I could use, because then colors (used by syntax highlighting) will be changed in accordance to the selected theme.

Since my custom editor also needs additional classification types (for instance a punctuation type), colors for those types won´t change when the user configures another theme (by switching from `Dark` to `Blue` theme, for instance). I would like to know how I can proffer theme-specific formats.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I have found to support multiple colour schemes (themes) is to hook into the [ThemeChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.platformui.vscolortheme.themechanged.aspx) event and then update your classification types accordingly.  Where possible I update my custom colours from predefined VS formats that are similar to my custom formats (e.g. use the standard VS **Keyword** colours to set the defaults on my custom keyword format), since I know these colours will likely be maintained by any custom themes the user has applied.

The [Visual F# Power Tools](https://github.com/fsprojects/VisualFSharpPowerTools/blob/a7d7aa9dd3d2a90f21c6947867ac7d7163b9f99a/src/FSharpVSPowerTools/SyntaxConstructClassifierProvider.cs) use this approach, which I discovered from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28099852/317739) answer.